'Plastic image': meaning in description of poetry
I've come across the notion plastic image(s) many times in the description of poetry, but never  fully grasped the meaning that it refers to.

Could you give us an example of where you've seen the term?

@GarethRees There are hundred on google books (e.g., searching "plastic image" poetry). I don't want to restrict the discussion to a particular example,, nor to too many,  for now.

Without specific examples, this question is not going to get an answer. You’re expecting too much if you want the answerer to look up and quote examples to explain the meaning of a term you want explained.

What a term means in English is more suitable for one of the English substacks.  For Literature, we need examples.
